# Git clone failed on Windows due to file name length

Tags: windows, git, ntfs, filenames

I'm trying to clone a Git repository on a Windows machine that has an NTFS volume.

Unfortunately I get several errors:

> error: unable to create file (...) Filename too long

The files in question are indeed very long but, according to what I know about [NTFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS), it should still work.

For example:

- file name is: 151 characters
- absolute filepath (including file name): 262 characters

This should still be accceptable and `git clone` should work. From what I found online and in NTFS documentation, restrictions are:

- max filename length: 255 characters
- max absolute path: ~32,000 characters

How come I can not clone that repository on a NTFS volume?

Comment: see [Filename too long in Git for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22575662/995714)

Comment: @phuclv YES that worked, thank you !

Answer (score 2):

You're *probably* hitting not NTFS storage restrictions, but Win32 API restrictions. The maximum path length that can be given to the OS functions such as CreateFile() (at Win32 layer) is a filesystem-independent limit of **260 characters** total.

This has its own article at Microsoft Docs:

- Microsoft: [Maximum Path Length Limitation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=registry)

Fortunately, recent Windows versions have raised the API limit to 32k characters – but you have to *opt in* through a Registry setting. How to do this is described in the same article (I faintly remember that Git for Windows' installer offers to automatically enable this option as well).

Comment: Thanks. While that makes perfect sense and it seems like it should solve the problem -> I applied it -> still doesn't work :( . And that's after a reboot as well. Strange...